# Why are classes and attributes not working on the Element-Plus UI library?

Tags: vue.js, element-plus

I installed the element-plus library on my Vue app properly by running:
`npm install element-plus --save`

and it is in fact working as I can use element-plus components, and even some attributes, but none of the classes are working, and many of the attributes don't work either.

I can't find any list of classes or attributes in the docs page on their website, but just looking at some of their components on their website, there are pre-defined classes and attributes, but when I use then, they don't work.

For example, the Carousel component shows this:
`<h3 text="2xl" justify="center">{{ item }}</h3>`

here we have the `text` and `justify` attributes, however, neither of them work! Why?

On the `Tag` page of of the docs, I see classes such as `mx-1` presumably `margin` horizontal, and I see attributes like `m='t-4'` presumably `margin-top` but again, none of them work!

Do I have to install or import something for these to work?